# visual c++ 2013 is showing error related to identifier. Identifier is not found but I have defined them but error is there

Tags: c++

Following is my code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int x;
    cout << "enter value one";
    cin >>x;
    cout << endl; 
    //cout << x;
do_print(x);
    return 0;
}
int do_print(int n)
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "\n I am great \n";
    square(n);
    return 0;
}
int square(int n)
{
    using namespace std;
    int y = n*n;
    cout << y;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and I am getting error.
Error   1   error C3861: 'do_print': identifier not found
Error   2  error C3861: 'square': identifier not found

I am using Visual C++ 2013. please tell me if there is something I am missing.

Comment: Move definition of function before its first usage. The order should be `square`, `do_print` and last `main`.

Comment: Thanks it is working now.Is there a way in which we can define it later also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In unction `do_print` you are using identifier `square`

```
square(n);
```

But in the point where the identifier is used it was not yet defined. So the compiler issues an error because it doen not know the definition of `square`,.

Place the identifier definition before its using either in function `do_print` or before main or before `do_print`

The same is valid for identifier do_print itself. Its declaration shall be before its using.

For example write the following way

```
int do_print( int );
int square( int );

int main()
{
```